# Is there any relationship xpage and [Java Servelet] on Domino web Engine Tab in Server document?

Tags: xpages

I'm thinking about performance tuning of xpages. 
In my understanding, XPages is nohting to do with [Java Servelet] on the Internet Protocols - Domino Web Engine tab of the Server document. But XPages is based on JSF techniques, and JSF uses servlet as its contloller. so I cannot be sure.
Does anyone know that?

Comment: Btw ... With have the next version (9) of domino is a start for using IHS :-) when you select to support TLS (SSL v3.1 or higher) there will be automatically a IHS (lightweight/minimal configuration) configured which acts like a kind of reverse proxy in front of the domino HTTP engine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to have a close look at: [XPages Portable Command Guide: A Compact Resource to XPages Application Development and the XSP Language](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132943050) that describes tuning parameter. And you are right: the servlet settings on the web engine page are for the legacy servlet 2.0 container. However the general HTTP settings are relevant until Domino starts using the IBM HTTP stack - but no plan has been announced for that.

Comment: Sorry for late replay. Thanks stwissel. Your answer was very helpful for me.